# How to disable DHCP on Netgear CG3700EMR-1CMNDS?

Tags: dhcp, cable-modem, dhcp-server

I just got a Netgear **CG3700EMR-1CMNDS** from my ISP. **How do I disable its DHCP server?** I'm unable to find the setting.

Comment: You don't. Because you actually have a [cable modem](https://www.comhem.se/blob/43614/2/manual-netgear-cg3700-data.pdf) you won't be able to replace the firmware

Comment: There is an option where I can disable the "Router mode". This probably disables DHCP as well. What do you think? The modem is assigned 4 public IPs.

Comment: How did you determine it was assigned 4 public ips because thats highly unusual.

Comment: I've read the knowledge base provided by my ISP. My premium plan got 2 IPs and the standard plans got only 2 public ones.

Comment: I've added a new answer. Do you think the answer is right?

Comment: Its your question.  You tell us?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Ramhound is correct this Device lets you change the DHCP scope of the network but the function cannot be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

By disabling the **router mode** both the NAT and the *DHCP* features will be *disabled*.

[image: A screenshot of the router mode switch and the related help article]

Answer (score 1):

It is sad that `Netgear cg3700emr` does not provide feature to disable DHCP and setting `Router Mode` to `No` just changes `DHCP`'s IP Pool. But...

I was able to disable `DHCP`, What I did:

1. Change `Router Mode` to `Yes`
2. Limited `DHCP IP Pool` range

   > Starting IP: 192.168.0.2
   >   Ending IP : 192.168.0.2
3. Added some random `MAC address` (e.g.: router's `MAC` address) into `IP Address reservation` list and assigned IP `192.168.0.2`
4. Save changes and restart
5. Profit

I know that this is not proper way to disable DHCP, but still... it works.

Your devices will go to Netgear's DHCP, sees that there is no free IP for him and goes to the next DHCP (if you have one), otherwise device gets fails with `Unable to obtain IP`.

The only problem is, your devices may take some time to connect to your network (like ~15-20 more secs).